# Excel Formula for an equation of permutation and combination

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have various options in the C2 cell as A,B,C & D (using list command in data validation). I have various options in cell D2 as 4,5,6. So I want to make formula for cell E2 in such a way that when A and 4 is selected in options it gives value 0.1. If A and 5 is selected, it gives 0.2. If B & 1 is selected it will give the value 0.6 and so on. All the permutations and combinations for the given columns in cell E2.

Please help with the formula.

Comment: Which version of excel?  Excel 2016 has a `switch` statement

Comment: yes excel 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Excel 2016, so my syntax may not be 100%, but the following should work, using the new [Switch](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) function (and assuming each value increments the answer by 0.1 - substitute your own correct values for each possible choice otherwise):

`=SWITCH(CONCATENATE(C2, D2), 'A4', 0.1, 'A5', 0.2, 'A6', 0.3, 'B4', 0.4, 'B5', 0.5, 'B6' 0.6, 'C4', 0.7, 'C5', 0.8, 'C6', 0.9, 'D4', 1.0, 'D5', 1.1, 'D6', 1.2)`

This goes in E2 and then copy-down for the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it all in the one cell E2?

You could list out the permutations:

```
List_1  List_2  ID  Result
    A      4    A4  0.1
    A      5    A5  0.2
    A      6    A6  0.3
    B      4    B4  0.4
    B      5    B5  0.5
    B      6    B6  0.6
    C      4    C4  0.7
    C      5    C5  0.8
    C      6    C6  0.9
    D      4    D4  1
    D      5    D5  1.1
    D      6    D6  1.2
```

and then use offset-match in E2 (assumes data shown above is in L24:O36):

```
=OFFSET($O$24,MATCH(C2&D2,$N$25:$N$36,0),0)
```

Comment: Yes I wanted in one cell E2. Thanks for the suggestion. I cantry this out.